# How to make this Rust code less redundant?

Tags: rust

How would you design this better in Rust? More Specifically is there a way to collapse the redundancy down using traits or enums?

Background: I have a C++ / Python background and this is my first attempt to see how the language actually flows after reading the Rust book. Not having class inheritance is something I don't really know how to design around yet.

```
trait TemperatureConversion {
    // https://www.nist.gov/pml/weights-and-measures/si-units-temperature
    fn to_celcius(&self) -> f64;
    fn to_fahrenheit(&self) -> f64;
    fn to_kelvin(&self) -> f64;
}

struct Celcius {
    value: f64,
}

struct Fahrenheit {
    value: f64,
}

struct Kelvin {
    value: f64,
}

impl Celcius {
    fn new(value: f64) -> Celcius {
        Celcius { value }
    }
}

impl Fahrenheit {
    fn new(value: f64) -> Fahrenheit {
        Fahrenheit { value }
    }
}

impl Kelvin {
    fn new(value: f64) -> Kelvin {
        Kelvin { value }
    }
}

impl TemperatureConversion for Celcius {
    fn to_celcius(&self) -> f64 {
        self.value
    }
    fn to_fahrenheit(&self) -> f64 {
        (self.value * 1.8) + 32.0
    }
    fn to_kelvin(&self) -> f64 {
        self.value + 273.15
    }
}

impl TemperatureConversion for Fahrenheit {
    fn to_celcius(&self) -> f64 {
        (self.value - 32.0) / 1.8
    }
    fn to_fahrenheit(&self) -> f64 {
        self.value
    }
    fn to_kelvin(&self) -> f64 {
        (self.value - 32.0) / 1.8 + 273.15
    }
}

impl TemperatureConversion for Kelvin {
    fn to_celcius(&self) -> f64 {
        self.value - 273.15
    }
    fn to_fahrenheit(&self) -> f64 {
        (self.value - 273.15) * 1.8 + 32.0
    }
    fn to_kelvin(&self) -> f64 {
        self.value
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = Celcius::new(100.0);
    println!("100C = {:.2}F or {:.2}K", c.to_fahrenheit(), c.to_kelvin());

    let f = Fahrenheit::new(100.0);
    println!("100F = {:.2}C or {:.2}K", f.to_celcius(), f.to_kelvin());

    let k = Kelvin::new(100.0);
    println!("100K = {:.2}C or {:.2}F", k.to_celcius(), k.to_fahrenheit());
}
```

edit: I believe this is the fix:

```
struct KelvinTemperature {
    kelvin: f64,
}

impl KelvinTemperature {
    fn new(kelvin: f64) -> KelvinTemperature {
        KelvinTemperature { kelvin }
    }

    fn from_celcius(value: f64) -> KelvinTemperature {
        KelvinTemperature {
            kelvin: value + 273.15,
        }
    }

    fn from_fahrenheit(value: f64) -> KelvinTemperature {
        KelvinTemperature {
            kelvin: (value - 32.0) / 1.8 + 273.15,
        }
    }

    fn to_celcius(&self) -> f64 {
        self.kelvin - 273.15
    }

    fn to_fahrenheit(&self) -> f64 {
        (self.kelvin - 273.15) * 1.8 + 32.0
    }
    
    fn to_kelvin(&self) -> f64 {
        self.kelvin
    }
}

fn main() {
    let temperature = KelvinTemperature::from_celcius(100.0);
    println!(
        "{:.2}C = {:.2}F = {:.2}K",
        temperature.to_celcius(),
        temperature.to_fahrenheit(),
        temperature.to_kelvin()
    );
}
```

Comment: The typical way to design this (in any language) is to have a canonical representation (e.g. Kelvin) and only implement the conversions to/from this representation, instead of all N^2 combinations.

Comment: @mkrieger1 makes sense, I guess I generally "abuse" class inheritance in other languages for more like a simple alias. I over thought this one trying to learn the language.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks! I didn't know that existed.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I've updated my question to provide a potential answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best design would likely be to avoid re-inventing the wheel and realize someone else has already done this better than we ever will in the time available. The [`uom`](https://crates.io/crates/uom) (Units Of Measurement) crate provides units for almost every unit you can think of as well as every combination of them (Even composite units like K*ft^2/sec). However that does not make for a very helpful explanation so lets just ignore it for now.

The first issue I see with this code is that it isn't very easy to expand. If you want to add a new temperature you need to add to the `TemperatureConversion` trait and implement a bunch of functions for all of your conversion rates. The first change I would make would be to turn `Temperature` into a trait so it is easier to work with.

```rust
pub trait Temperature: Copy {
    fn to_kelvin(self) -> f64;
    fn from_kelvin(x: f64) -> Self;
    
    /// Convert self to a different unit of temperature
    fn convert<T: Temperature>(self) -> T {
        T::from_kelvin(self.to_kelvin())
    }
}
```

This also gives us the benefit of letting us use it to constrain type parameters later.

```rust
pub fn calculate_stuff<T: Temperature>(a: T, b: T) -> T;
```

Next, since we know that temperatures will all be implemented in the same way and there might be a bunch of them, it may be easier to make a macro for them.

```rust
macro_rules! define_temperature {
    ($name:ident, $kelvin_at_zero:literal, $kelvin_per_unit:literal) => {
        #[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
        pub struct $name(f64);
        
        impl Temperature for $name {
            fn to_kelvin(self) -> f64 {
                self.0 * $kelvin_per_unit + $kelvin_at_zero
            }
            
            fn from_kelvin(x: f64) -> Self {
                Self((x - $kelvin_at_zero) / $kelvin_per_unit)
            }
        }
    };
}

define_temperature! {Kelvin, 1.0, 1.0} 
define_temperature! {Celsius, 273.1, 1.0} 
define_temperature! {Fahrenheit, 255.3722, 0.5555}
```

The macro makes it easy to implement a bunch of different units based on their conversion rates, but the trait is not too restrictive so we could potentially implement units that do not follow a linear scale.

Comment: Nice answer! I would also suggest making the inner value in the newtype `pub`, since there's no reason to prevent consumers from doing what they want with the value.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I have a lot to learn still because everything you explained here I didn't retain from reading the rust book. derive attribute, macros, `self` vs `&self` vs `Self`. Any chance you can expand on the `calculate_stuff` generic function?

Coming from a C/C++ world I always seen "function macros" as dirty so I guess I just skipped over it unintentionally.